# JS: access unrounded width of user loaded svg

Tags: javascript, svg

I am programming a JS applet. The user chooses an SVG file to load. The SVG file has a widht and height attribute and they are not necessarily integers. If I put the file content into an img element these values are rounded to integers. I need to access the unrounded values.

Comment: load the SVG yourself, parse it (it's XML), extract the values you need.

Comment: @RobertLongson Is there a JS command to parse?

Comment: @RobertLongson found it: new DOMParser().parseFromString(...)

Comment: Why load it in an IMG and not in a shadowDOM; where you can then do ``.shadowRoot.querySelector("svg").getAttribute("width")``

Answer (score 1):

Robert Longson suggested a way, here is my implementation but it might not be the best.

```js
let svg = new DOMParser().parseFromString(fileContent,"image/svg+xml");
let width = svg.rootElement.width.baseVal.value;
let height = svg.rootElement.height.baseVal.value;
```

Comment: The values retrieved this way will still be strings, optionally suffixed with any of the valid CSS length/percentage units. If you know the values exist and will be px values, you are good. Otherwise further treatment might be needed. For the full algorithm see [Intrinsic sizing properties of SVG content](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/coords.html#SizingSVGInCSS)

Comment: @ccprog, they won't be strings, this is the SVG DOM, it returns floats. Note that animVal is what's rendered but it's read only. baseVal you can change though and if you've not used SMIL baseVal = animVal

Comment: @ccprog Thanks for pointing that. I just ran tests and up to now I only got "number" as an output of typeof() applied to those values.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thx for correcting me. Still, you might need to read [`baseVal.unitType`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/types.html#__svg__SVGLength__unitType) or handle cases where some of the attributes are missing.